# Moving a point using cordinate in 2D OpenGL Python

Tags: python, opengl, glut, point

Suppose I have a point in pixel (200,200), and I would like to just shift it to (400,400) pixel. Is there any way to do it without `glClear()` as I don't want my other objects to get erased?

Here is the code that I am using for drawing a single point:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *


def draw_points(x0,y0):
    glPointSize(5) 
    glBegin(GL_POINTS)
    glVertex2f(x0,y0)
    glEnd()


def iterate():
    glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0.0, 1000, 0.0, 1000, 0.0, 1.0)
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def showScreen():
    elapesed_ms = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) 

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    iterate()
    glColor3f(255, 255, 255)
    
    draw_points(200,200)


    glutSwapBuffers()




glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)
glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000)
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
wind = glutCreateWindow(b"") 
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)

glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: Only if you know the color that was at the point's location before the point was drawn. However, the usual way is to redraw the scene every frame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you please elaborate? If the color before the point was drawn is black.

Comment: So you can just draw a black point over the white point and the point is gone.

Comment: ohhhh! and another way is to redraw the scene every single time with glClear in a loop if there are any movements, right?

Comment: Yes, this is the usual way.